# How to force words that start with an italic uppercase letter "W" to be better aligned agaist left-hand edge of minipage

Tags: pdftex, luatex, minipage, justification

Is it my eyes or has anyone else noticed that the left justification of an italic *W* in a `minipage` environment does not appear to be as "flush" as other left justified letters?

Consider, for instance, the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\headsep=-25pt \textheight=9.5in
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.42in}
\bfseries {\color{blue}{SENECA:}} \, \textit{The Time Will Come When Diligent Research Over Long Periods Will Bring to Light Things Which Now Lie Hidden. A Single Lifetime, Even Though Entirely Devoted to the Sky, Would Not be Enough for the Investigation of So Vast a Subject\ldots. And So This Knowledge {\color{red}{Will}} be Unfolded Only Through Long Successive Ages. There Will Come a Time {\color{red}{When}} Our Descendants Will be Amazed That We Did Not Know Things That are So Plain to Them\ldots. Many Discoveries are Reserved for Ages Still to Come,\linebreak {\color{red}{When}} Memory of Us Will Have Been Effaced.}
\end{minipage}

\vskip 15pt

\begin{minipage}{5.42in}
\bfseries {\color{blue}{SENECA:}} \, \textit{The Time Will Come When Diligent Research Over Long Periods Will Bring to Light Things Which Now Lie Hidden. A Single Lifetime, Even Though Entirely Devoted to the Sky, Would Not be Enough for the Investigation of So Vast a Subject\ldots. And So This Knowledge Will be Unfolded Only Through Long Successive Ages. There Will Come a Time When Our Descendants Will be Amazed That We Did Not Know Things That are So Plain to Them\ldots. Many Discoveries are Reserved for Ages Still to Come,\linebreak When Memory of Us Will Have Been Effaced.}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The second minipage is the same as the first, except the three left justified *W* words are not in red to illustrate that the phenomenon is not caused by the adding of color---which was included in the first minipage for visual emphasis.

The code was compiled with `lualatex`; though, the output appears to me to be the same when I compile with `pdflatex`.

QUESTION: Does anyone know what might be causing italicized *W* words to not be as nicely left justified in a `minipage` as other words that begin with different letters? Also, is there a way to fix the visual problem?

Thank you.

Comment: It's unrelated to minipage and just your eyes are looking at the bottom of the letter and not thetop left extreme serif [The code posted does not produce the image shown it makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7DYQ.png)

Comment: Many thanks @DavidCarlisle for pointing this out.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting to clarify the query's objective. Feel free to revert.

Comment: That's fine @Mico.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You asked:

> is there a way to fix the visual problem?

Yes: Load the [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package.

Consider the following minimalist LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\obeylines

\itshape
When
Will
What

\bfseries
When
Will
What
\end{document}
```

By default, i.e., if the `microtype` package isn't loaded, this document produces:

[image]

But with `microtype` loaded, one gets:

[image]

Comment: ohh you just beat me I'll delete mine:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - So sorry. ... :-)

Comment: +1: Wasn't aware of the \obeylines command!

Comment: Many thanks @Mico.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using OpTeX then there is equivalent to microtype `\load[mte] \emablemte` which means micro-typographic extension.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.